# Borel $\sigma$-algebra Intuition

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-sets

I'm trying to get some intuition for the role of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra with an example, but I'm not sure how to interpret parts of this example using math.

**Setup**

From my notes, a function $X: (\Omega,\mathcal{F}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ is a measurable function if

\begin{equation}
X^{-1}(B) = \{ \omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \in B \} \in \mathcal{F}\ \text{for all}\ B \in \mathcal{B}.
\end{equation}

$\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra using $\Omega$, and $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

**Example**

I'm trying to make sense of this definition with a die roll. Let's say you roll a fair die once, so the set of possible outcomes is $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$ $\mathcal{F}$ is the set of all subsets of $\Omega$ ($\mathcal{F}$ has other propeties too), so it has sets like $\{\{1\},\{1,2\},\dots,\{1,2,3,4,5,6\},\dots\}.$

**Question**

What's the "physical" intuition of $\mathcal{F}$ here? If we're only rolling the die once, I don't see why we need to list all these other sets.

As such, what does the Borel $\sigma$-algebra hold, then? From how I understand things now, it would just have numbers like $\{\{1/6\},\{2/6\},\dots,\{1\},\dots\}$, but I think I'm misunderstanding something. Thank you!

Comment: The Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ is defined regardless of the measurable functions from $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. It is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by every open set in the (Euclidean, in this case) topology of $\mathbb{R}$ and does not depend on the choice of $X$.

Comment: Honestly, the Borel $\sigma$ algebra doesn't do much when you're dealing with a finite, or even infinite discreet, sample space. We need it when we move on to continuously valued sample spaces. I hate to discourage someone who is trying to dig into the details, but I might advise you to not worry to much about it now.

Answer (score 1):

The elements of $\mathcal F$ are "events" in the sense of probability theory.  So, for example, a gambler might win if he rolls $2$, $4$, or $6$, but lose otherwise.  So we need to know about the set $\{2,4,6\}$.  In particular, we may want to know its probability $\mathbb P(\{2,4,6\}) = 1/2$.  Or we may want to do expectations involving this event, and so on.

The sigma-algebra $\mathcal F$ serves as the domain for the probability measure $\mathbb P$.  We are only slightly interested in $\mathcal F$.  We are much more interested in $\mathbb P$.

Comment: Ok; that makes sense. So in that case, is $\mathcal{B}$ the analogous sigma algebra for the set of all possible outcomes?